Is it possible to compare the output probabilities of two machine learning models?
Let's suppose I have two classification machine learning models: $\text{Model}_1$ and $\text{Model}_2$. Each of them are not necessarily the same algorithm, and have not been trained necessarily with the same data set, but have the same target.
Given input data $X_i$ to $\text{Model}_i$, the probability of that data being the target is $x_i$; you can think it in terms of math as $\mathbb{P}(M_i = 1|X_i) = x_i$.
My questions is, how do I know that $\mathbb{P}(M_1 = 1|X_1) = x_1$ is comparable to $\mathbb{P}(M_2 = 1|X_2) = x_2$, in other words, how to pass from $x_1$ to $x_2$; is it even possible? Could I compare in some way the probability outputs of 2 machine learning models?

It's not completely clear to me what you are doing. You could assess the accuracy of both models' predictions using proper scoring rules and compare these, but it does not sound like this is what you want. Or you could use a meta-model to model the output from $M_2$ as a function of the outputs of $M_1$, and then do prediction.
